# how to detect only windows 2003 computers from domain

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Consider domain of all windows based computers. from these computers i want to detect only windows server 2003 computers.

I have all machine names of all machines in domain. then how to  determine OS version  from  machine name. I have used `Environment.OSVersion` to get os version of local computer. How can i obtain OS version of remote computer if i know remote computer name ?

Comment: Apart from the fact that I already provided an answer, why is this voted to close ("off topic")? It sounds like a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) to access the remote computer's
[Win32_OperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class instance.

```
using (var mc = new ManagementClass(@"\\" + computerName + @"\root\cimv2:Win32_OperatingSystem"))
{
    foreach (var obj in mc.GetInstances())
    {
       if (((bool)obj.Properties["Primary"].Value))
       {
          int productType = (int)obj.Properties["ProductType"].Value;
          string version = obj.Properties["Version"].Value.ToString();
          bool isServer = (productType == 2 || productType == 3); // "Domain Controller" or "Server

          if (version == "5.2.3790" && isServer)
          {
             // "Caption" should contain something like "Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003..."
             // Please resist parsing that, however.                  
             Console.WriteLine(obj.Properties["Caption"].Value);
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

For details on the properties and what values are available, see the MSDN pages for the [Win32_OperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class.

Comment: Thanks. but i didnt understand what meant by:properties["Primary"].value

Comment: Do yo mean that syntactic construct, or the special property value "Primary"?

Comment: It just means that a single computer could have multiple operating systems installed. The code above only checks the "primary" one, which should be the one which is currently booted (as dormant once could hardly answer the WMI query).